# Cookie not set with jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies

This rather simplistic code is not working for me, which puzzles me :

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
    var myCookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
    alert(myCookie);
});
```

[**jsFiddle test**](http://jsfiddle.net/8XZN8/7/)

I had imported the `jquery.cookie.js`.

What am I doing wrong ?

---

**Note** : when I look for a the cookie in my browser's tab ressources, I can't find it either. Tried it this far with jsFiddle and localhost, none work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is the cookie.js doesn't link to a javascript file, it links to a **GitHub Gist** page

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

Just copy the code into JSFiddle

and then

```
 alert(myCookie); // Will work
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8XZN8/9/)

**CDN** : http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: Any chance I can still get the plug-in from internet and have it work ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to hot link from github

download the jquery.cookie.js to your local drive and reference to that and it will work.

Comment: Reference to your local drive?

Comment: @Connor : he means basically downloading the file.

Comment: Well, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: What doesn't it make sense ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the jQuery cookie plugin file is not loading. Check the JS console to view the errors. The URL you've included as the cookie plugin is returning HTML.